# Amazon Virtual Desktop: python script unable to fetch Clipboard : Access denied

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, window, clipboard, pywin32

Amazon Virtual Desktop,

Python Script doing good stuff But unable to access data from clipboard

We have no access for C Drive and available D drive for users data

Trying the following snippet :-

```
import win32clipboard

# get clipboard data
win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
data = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
print data
```

Gives me following error :-

```
win32clipboard.OpenClipboard() pywintypes.error: (5, 'OpenClipboard', 'Access is denied.')
```

Any work around or solution for it ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at : https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter

```
#from Tkinter import Tk    # Python v2.x
from tkinter import Tk    # Python v3.x
tkint = Tk()
copied_val = tkint.clipboard_get()
```